# space between double borders

Tags: html, css, border, border-spacing

I am trying to add a double border using `border: 10px double red;` but how can I control the thickness and spacing of the borders? I want the border to have a 1px thickness. If I just change border to 1px the borders are overlapping and retty much only one border visible. I also tried with border-width 1px but same result.

I've been trying with border-spacing property as well, but couldn't get it to work.

Here a screenshot of what I am trying to accomplish: https://share.getcloudapp.com/JrugmEG2

Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7Lw21z85/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
   <span class="box">
      <h1 class="heading">
         Heading text
      </h1>
      <p>
         some text :)
      </p>
   </span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
text-align: center;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
padding: 8%;
background-color: black;
}

.heading {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: black;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
color: black;
}

.box {
  background-color: white;
  border: 10px double red;
  padding: 8%;
  outline: 15px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `box-shadow` for making illusion of two borders around the element

```css
.container {
text-align: center;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
padding: 8%;
background-color: black;
}

.heading {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: black;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
color: black;
}

.box {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 8%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #B38D6A, 0 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 0 6px #B38D6A, 0 0 0 11px #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <span class="box">
      <h1 class="heading">
         Heading text
      </h1>
      <p>
         some text :)
      </p>
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to solve the issue! However, I can't really see how to change the red color? I want to use #B38D6A - Been trying some hex to HSL converters but no luck :(

Comment: Got it! box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px hsl(29deg 32% 56%), 0 0 0 5px hsl(0deg 0% 100%), 0 0 0 6px hsl(29deg 32% 56%), 0 0 0 15px hsl(0deg 0% 97%); - Thank you!

Comment: I've updated the example. Please see the changes and mark the answer as useful if it helps you

Answer (score 2):

You can consider `outline-offset`

```css
.box {
  margin:15px;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
  outline:1px solid red;
  outline-offset:9px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: This should be selected as the answer and I believe accomplishes what the op wanted. The selected answer above, while it works, only gives the "illusion". [Outline-Offset](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_outline-offset.asp) literally creates that second border that op was asking for. Not to mention, Temani's solution is so much more simple. You can control the spacing of both borders by changing the value for outline-offset, and you can control the thickness of each border by changing the border value and/or the outline value

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a built-in way to adjust the spacing in the double border itself, however, here is one way where you can adjust thickness for each solid border in nested divs.

```css
.container {
text-align: center;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
padding: 8%;
background-color: black;
}

.heading {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: black;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
color: black;
}

.outer-box {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 2%;
  outline: 5px solid #ffffff;
}

.middle-box {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 4%;
  outline: 5px solid #ffffff;
}

.box {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 4%;
  outline: 5px solid #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="outer-box">
<div class="middle-box">
   <div class="box">
      <h1 class="heading">
         Heading text
      </h1>
      <p>
         some text :)
      </p>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
</div>
```